# Meteor: Is there a way to be notified when a template is take off the dom?

Tags: events, templates, dom, meteor

The template has a destroyed event but that event is call when the template is no longer in the dom.

I want to access the template before is take off the dom.

I want to close a tooltip before i can put another template in the dom and close old one.

Comment: Would it be possible to show us what you actually have, or what you tried? It's a bit hard to answer without code in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`destroyed` is the only template teardown event that Spark exposes right now. I don't think we actually guarantee whether it is called before the nodes are physically removed from the DOM, or after.

I'm not totally sure, but it sounds like what you're trying to do is to manually create a floating tooltip DIV after your template is created (I guess from a mouseover event handler or maybe even from `created`), and then manually remove it from the DOM when the template goes off the screen. Here some ways to solve this problem:

- Instead of manually creating the tooltip DIV, put it inside the template, and change the class to show/hide it (maybe using a session variable that is set based on where the mouse is hovering.)
- Hold a pointer to the tooltip DIV in a `tooltip` attribute on the template object. Then from `removed`, you can just remove `this.tooltip`.
- Give the tooltip a unique id or class name, and use jquery or `querySelectorAll` (or Meteor's not-yet-documented `DomUtils.find`) to find the element by id or class and remove it.

If this isn't sufficient, I'd be open to adding more functionality, but I'd need to better understand what you're trying to do :) The best way to request new functionality (other than writing it yourself :P) is to submit a GitHub issue, but it would need to come with a detailed example of what you're trying to do and why the new hook is needed. Thanks.